# Reactotron doesn't work with NextJS because of SSR

Tags: javascript, reactjs, frontend, next.js, reactotron

I'm configuring the redux store for my NextJS application and i usually use the Reactotron library to inspect the store. But, NextJS is server side rendering and if i import the configuration in the app file, it gives an error `window is not defined`

That's my config file: 
https://github.com/LauraBeatris/amazon-next/blob/develop/src/config/ReactotronConfig.js

And my app file: 
https://github.com/LauraBeatris/amazon-next/blob/develop/src/pages/_app.js

I want to know if there's a way of using Reactotron with NextJS

Answer (score 2):

In NextJS you can dynamically import a module on the client side only. You should import it like [this](https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/dynamic-import#with-no-ssr):

```
import dynamic from "next/dynamic"

const DynamicComponentWithNoSSR = dynamic(
  () =>  import '~/config/ReactotronConfig',
  { ssr: false }
)
```

But I'm not sure if Reactotron will work the way you expect, as I don't know the library.